# Extract all unique URL from log with only POST type of the request

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, grep, cut

I've got a log file with the such type of the records:

`41.201.181.27 - [2019-04-06 18:22:02] "GET /images/stands/photo_mois.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://example.com/popup.php?choix=mois" "Mozilla/4.0" "-"`

I've got the script for getting all records with unique URLs:
`cut -f4 -d\" < logfile | sort -u`
How i need to change it for getting unique URLs with only POST type of the request?

Comment: Could you please show more input and expected sample output in your question and let us know then.

Comment: I need to find all records from log with unique URLs and with POST type. The script from above finds only unique URLs and i want to transform it for finding POST records with unique URLs.

Comment: Honestly its not clear as of now, if you could add more lines in sample of input and sample of expected output it will give us clear picture of your question.

Comment: In case you didn't know, your current `cut` command doesn't extract the request URL but the referrer ; from the log extract you posted it would extract `http://example.com/popup.php?choix=mois` rather than `/images/stands/photo_mois.jpg`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always pipe to `cut` command. Something like below

```sh
grep POST /path/to/myfile.log | cut -f4 -d\"  | sort -u
```